# Elastic Go cannot find document

Tags: elasticsearch, go

Sorry if this is a dumb question. I'm using a service which was built using Elasticsearch client for Go. I run the service and now seems like the elasticsearch server have the index of the data. However, when I tried to query those data with `http://129.94.14.234:9200/chromosomes/chromosome/1`, I got `{"_index":"chromosomes","_type":"chromosome","_id":"1","_version":1,"found":true,"_source":{"id":"1","length":249250621}}` I checked that the SQL query from the database have those data. Now the question is that, how do I check that my elasticsearch index have those data? Or If anyone can tell me what might be wrong on the code that'll be great as well.

Here's the code that I assume adding the documents to `chromosomes` index.

```
    func (c ChromosomeIndexer) AddDocuments(db *sql.DB, client *elastic.Client, coordID int) {
    sqlQuery := fmt.Sprintf("SELECT seq_region.name, seq_region.length FROM seq_region WHERE seq_region.`name` REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]{1,2}$|^[xXyY]$|(?i)^mt$' AND seq_region.`coord_system_id` = %d", coordID)
    stmtOut, err := db.Prepare(sqlQuery)
    check(err)
    defer stmtOut.Close()
    stmtOut.Query()
    rows, err := stmtOut.Query()
    defer rows.Close()
    check(err)

    chromoFn := func(rows *sql.Rows, bulkRequest *elastic.BulkService) {
        var name string
        var length int
        err = rows.Scan(&name, &length)
        check(err)
        chromo := Chromosome{ID: name, Length: length}
        fmt.Printf("chromoID: %s\n", chromo.ID)
        req := elastic.NewBulkIndexRequest().
            OpType("index").
            Index("chromosomes").
            Type("chromosome").
            Id(chromo.ID).
            Doc(chromo)
        bulkRequest.Add(req)
    }
    elasticutil.IterateSQL(rows, client, chromoFn)

}
```

This service have other index which I can query the data with no problem, I only have problem when querying `chromosomes` data.

Please let me know if I need to put more code so that I can give a bit more context on the problem, I just started on Go and Elasticsearch, and I tried reading the documentation, but it just leads to more confusion.

Comment: I got the service from here https://github.com/shusson/genesearch

Comment: "I only have problem when querying chromosomes data". What problem? The code you show doesn't query ES at all. And in the very first paragraph you demonstrate that you *can* query the index successfully. It's really not clear what you're asking.

Comment: @Peter Sorry, if my question is not clear, as I'm still trying to understand ES and Go. So the piece of code that I attached there is for adding documents to the `chromosomes` index that I have. I can query the index such that if I go `http://129.94.14.234:9200/chromosomes/` I'll get the json file with the mappings of the chromosome, but what I want is the data on that index. If you're willing to see the repo of the service, it might give you better understanding of what I'm asking.

Comment: http://129.94.14.234:9200/chromosomes/_search

Comment: @Peter I can see the data with `/chromosomes/_search`, how do I get the data based on id? Also I'm still confused what's the `type` for?